# Pandasgui to read a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, visualization, pandasgui, charmap

I have a problem, I am trying to use pandasgui to read a dataframe, but it gives me the following error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c4' in position 276398: character maps to

could someone help me??

use pandasgui to read a dataframe

Comment: I've the same issue. Moreover, one day it works, on the another it doesn't (on exactly the same df).